# Collection View Dragging Cells when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have one `UICollectionView` with many sections and cells. I have used custom `UICollectionView` layout to achieve this design. It has scroll on both horizontal and vertical, with some static cells. Check the video for more details. All the data is setting proper.

[Video Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7b26tr3squymgug/CollectionView%20Issue.mov?dl=0).

Issue is with dragging. I want to drag the cells in the vertical direction and if its within the visible cells there is no problem. But when the cell is drag to scroll the `UICollectionView` and to bottom there is layout issues with top sticky sections.

[image]

Blue remains static when scrolling from left to right and red remains static when scrolling to bottom.

I have implemented drag using longpress gesture. And used `CADisplayLink` to scroll the `UICollectionView` while dragging. It would be better if any suggestions on how to scroll the `UICollectionView` while dragging the cell and how to keep the sticky cells without and layout issues.